# Devstack: TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, django, devstack

I am getting this error when run horizon in devstack in eclipse. may be it's configuration error but I cannot solve it. please help

```
 WARNING:root:No local_settings file found.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/stack/git/horizon/manage.py", line 23, in <module>
        execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
        utility.execute()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 303, in execute
        settings.INSTALLED_APPS
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 48, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 44, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/home/stack/git/horizon/openstack_dashboard/settings.py", line 339, in <module>
        from horizon.utils import secret_key
      File "/home/stack/git/horizon/horizon/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        from horizon.base import Dashboard  # noqa
      File "/home/stack/git/horizon/horizon/base.py", line 45, in <module>
        from horizon import loaders
      File "/home/stack/git/horizon/horizon/loaders.py", line 57, in <module>
        _loader = TemplateLoader()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.8-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py", line 50, in __init__
        super(BaseLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Django loader file is showing error when run horizon. it showed type error in argument

```
import warnings

from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango20Warning

from .base import Origin
from .engine import Engine


class LoaderOrigin(Origin):
    def __init__(self, display_name, loader, name, dirs):
        super(LoaderOrigin, self).__init__(display_name)
        self.loader, self.loadname, self.dirs = loader, name, dirs

    def reload(self):
        return self.loader(self.loadname, self.dirs)[0]


def find_template(*args, **kwargs):
    return Engine.get_default().find_template(*args, **kwargs)


def get_template(*args, **kwargs):
    return Engine.get_default().get_template(*args, **kwargs)


def get_template_from_string(*args, **kwargs):
    return Engine.get_default().get_template_from_string(*args, **kwargs)


def render_to_string(*args, **kwargs):
    return Engine.get_default().render_to_string(*args, **kwargs)


def select_template(*args, **kwargs):
    return Engine.get_default().select_template(*args, **kwargs)


# This line must remain at the bottom to avoid import loops.
from .loaders import base


class BaseLoader(base.Loader):
    _accepts_engine_in_init = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        warnings.warn(
            "django.template.loader.BaseLoader was superseded by "
            "django.template.loaders.base.Loader.",
            RemovedInDjango20Warning, stacklevel=2)
        super(BaseLoader, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I just want to run horizon in eclipse. setting another project in preference like cinder, nova etc.

Comment: its default file of django after setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Horizon requires `Django>=1.4.2,<1.7`, you're using Django 1.8 here (see [`requirements.txt`](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/requirements.txt))

The `__init__` arguments for `BaseLoader` have changed between those two versions.

You need to fix your environment and dependencies if you want this to work.

Answer (score 0):

May be there is no. of criteria for that type of problem ,
but in my case i am not initialize all the parameters in `__init__()` method 
so this create a problem 
`def __init__(self, value, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        super(Custom_Vali, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`
....
....
Run
`test_c = Custom_Vali.get_error(89)`
OR
`test_c = Custom_Vali.get_error(value = 89)`

O/P: `TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)`

SOLUTION:
just set value=None or value = 0 in `__init__`
`def __init__(self, value=0, *args, **kwargs):
        self.value = value
        super(Custom_Vali, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`